# Best way to manipulate DOCX files in PHP

Tags: php, ms-word

I know there are librarys such as PHPWord or PHPDocx, but PHPWord is inefficient and can lose variables and PHPDocx is a paid library so I can't use that. Is there some type of field in word which remains constant and is easily legible which I can use for my replacement fields in my php script? 
I've tried str_replace with tags like ${TAG1} but sometimes these characters get seperated by word tags and therefore the script doesn't find them.. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [bookmarks](http://wordprocessing.about.com/od/wordquicktips/qt/insertbm.htm). If you create a bookmark with the name "title" the document.xml will contain these tags:

```
<w:bookmarkStart w:id="0" w:name="title"/><w:r><w:t>World</w:t></w:r><w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0"/>
```

[How to modify xml file using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193528/how-to-modify-xml-file-using-php)

Comment: How would I go about changing the content of the bookmark from the name though? I'm not very familiar with XML and this doesn't look like correct XML to me.

Comment: It is just a part of a word xml. You search for the bookmark, remove all nodes between w:bookmarkStart and w:bookmarkEnd and add you content as sibbling just after the bookmark. Play arround with word to find out how to format text with word xml.

Comment: I've tried to get the word bookmarks by doing $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName( "w:bookmarkStart" ); and using a foreach to loop through all of the ids by getAttribute('w:id'); but I get no result, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Nevermind, I found a solution using NodeValues.

Comment: Sorry I did no xml editng for some time. The problem was that u used the "w:" prefix you have to use " $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName( "bookmarkStart"); WITHOIUT the prefix