# Edit XML using PHP

Tags: php, xml, xmldom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to modify xml file using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193528/how-to-modify-xml-file-using-php)

I have an xml that looks like this:

```
<host host-name="www.1.com">
   <root-directory>c:/public_html</root-directory>
</host>
<host host-name="www.2.com">
   <root-directory>c:/public_html</root-directory>
</host>
```

I need do modify the xml using php like this

If the value of host-name = www.2.com

change the value of root-directory in c:/public_html/blahblah

So the final result would be:

```
<host host-name="www.1.com">
   <root-directory>c:/public_html</root-directory>
</host>
<host host-name="www.2.com">
   <root-directory>c:/public_html/blahblah</root-directory>
</host>
```

I really need some help. Thanks!

Update:

oh, i forgot to mention that i'm not a programmer, anyway here is what i've tried

```
$xmlDomain= "www.2.com";
$nomefile='myfile.xml';
$xmlDoc = new DomDocument();
$xmlDoc->load($nomefile); 
$Xroot = $xmlDoc->documentElement;
$products = $Xroot->getElementsByTagName("host");
$length = $products->length;
for ($i=$length-1;$i>=0;$i--)
{
$p = $products->item($i);    
$pid = $p->getAttribute("host-name");

if ($pid == $xmlDomain)
{  
$parent = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName("root-directory");     
$parent->nodeValue = 'c:/public_html/blahblah';             
}
}
$strxml = $xmlDoc->saveXML();
$handle = fopen($nomefile, "w");
fwrite($handle, $strxml);
fclose($handle);
```

Comment: You can use the DOMDocument from PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I needed to get my head away from writing documentation for a minute, so here it is:

```
function modifyRootDirectoryFormHosts(DOMDocument $doc, $hostNameToLookFor, $newRootDirectory)
{
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
    $items = $xpath->query(sprintf('//host[@host-name="%s"]', $hostNameToLookFor));

    if (count($items) > 0)
    {
        foreach($items as $item)
        {
            foreach($item->getElementsByTagName('root-directory') as $rootDirElement)
            {
                $rootDirElement->removeChild($rootDirElement->firstChild);
                $rootDirElement->appendChild($doc->createTextNode($newRootDirectory));
            }
        }
    }
}

$xmlSource = <<<XML
<root>
<host host-name="www.1.com">
   <root-directory>c:/public_html</root-directory>
</host>
<host host-name="www.2.com">
   <root-directory>c:/public_html</root-directory>
</host>
</root>
XML;


$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xmlSource);

modifyRootDirectoryFormHosts($doc, 'www.2.com', 'c:/public_html/blahblah');

echo $doc->saveXML();
```

output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
<host host-name="www.1.com">
   <root-directory>c:/public_html</root-directory>
</host>
<host host-name="www.2.com">
   <root-directory>c:/public_html/blahblah</root-directory>
</host>
</root>
```

Comment: hi Kris, here is the result <?xml version="1.0"?>
:D any clues?

Comment: That's the first line of an xml file. technically a processing instruction, telling xml parsers something about how to interpret the rest of the file. perfectly valid.

Comment: What I meant to say is thats the only line left after running the code, it deleted everything else.

Comment: does your input file have a root tag? sounds like you didn't use the same code i did, or you're using invalid input xml.

Comment: sorry, i'm having some problems copying the code here. http://pastebin.com/nqZYKcRi

Comment: and here your function adapted to my needs http://pastebin.com/vMhz3A4z

Comment: you still haven't answered the root tag question, the xml in your original question was invalid so I had to add a root tag. does the file have one? is the file completely valid?

Comment: Kris i'm sorry but i'm having some problems copying the code here, here is the of the original xml  http://pastebin.com/nqZYKcRi * this is the root tag <resin xmlns="http://caucho.com/ns/resin" xmlns:resin="urn:java:com.caucho.resin">