# I want to modify the existing data in xml file using php

Tags: php, xml

Here is my xml file

```
<books>
  <book>
      <author>Jack Herrington</author>
      <title>PHP Hacks</title>
      <publisher>O'Reilly</publisher>
  </book>
  <book>
      <author>Jack Herrington</author>
      <title>Podcasting Hacks</title>
      <publisher>O'Reilly</publisher>
  </book>
</books>
```

I need edit the second title `<title>Podcasting Hacks</title>` to `<title>Podcasting Pops</title>` using php script.

Anyone give me a suggestion to do this. Thanks

Comment: Does it need to be dynamic (values you wish to edit are always different and this is an example) or is it static (you always need to change the same values)?

Comment: Please see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3577641/1919238

Comment: You can load your XML into a PHP object using [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php). You can manipulate the object and then write the object to a file as XML again. All you need is SimpleXML.

Comment: ya, need to be dynamic

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193528/how-to-modify-xml-file-using-php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748014/updating-xml-node-with-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

file 'test.php':

```
<?php
include 'books.php';
$b=new books();
//1. load books from xml to array
$arr=$b->load('books.xml');         

//2. modify title
for($i=0,$ms=count($arr);$i<$ms;$i++)
{
  if($arr[$i]['fields']['title']=='Podcasting Hacks')
  {
     $arr[$i]['fields']['title']='Podcasting Pops';
  }
}

//3. save array to xml
$b->save('out.xml',$arr);           
?>
```

file 'books.php':

```
<?php
  class books
  {
     //load books from xml to array
     public function load($fname)
     {
        $doc=new DOMDocument();

        if($doc->load($fname))  $res=$this->parse($doc);
        else                    throw new Exception('error load XML');

        return $res;
     }


     private function parse($doc)
     {
        $xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
        $items = $xpath->query("book");
        $result = array();
        foreach($items as $item)
        {
           $result[]=array('fields'=>$this->parse_fields($item));
        }
        return $result;
     }


     private function parse_fields($node)
     {
        $res=array();
        foreach($node->childNodes as $child)
        {
           if($child->nodeType==XML_ELEMENT_NODE)
           {
              $res[$child->nodeName]=$child->nodeValue;
           }
        }
        return $res;
     }


     //save array to xml
     public function save($fname, $rows)
     {
        $doc = new DOMDocument('1.0','utf-8');
        $doc->formatOutput = true;

        $books = $doc->appendChild($doc->createElement('books'));

        foreach($rows as $row)
        {
           $book=$books->appendChild($doc->createElement('book'));
           foreach($row['fields'] as $field_name=>$field_value)
           {
              $f=$book->appendChild($doc->createElement($field_name));
              $f->appendChild($doc->createTextNode($field_value));
           }
        }

        file_put_contents($fname, $doc->saveXML());
     }

  }
?>
```