# Graph visualization library from xml in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any javascript library for building graph from an xml file.
I want the graph to be visualisable and editable in a php page.

Comment: you can try www.chartjs.org

Comment: -1: searching in the internet for what you need gives you good results. chartjs suggested by Mahdi Rashidi is the second result

Comment: you can't build graph with charjs

Answer (score 0):

First you can build chart with xml:

http://buildinternet.com/2009/07/how-to-build-quick-and-easy-charts-from-xml-data/

And edit xml in php:

[How to modify xml file using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193528/how-to-modify-xml-file-using-php)